# Whats wrong with this tabularx?

Tags: tabularx

I'm trying to create a table with tabularx, with different column widths:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{sbs}
    \caption[Oligonucleotides]{List of oligonucleotides ...}\\

    \toprule
    \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence} & \textbf{Application}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \toprule
    \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence} & \textbf{Application}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
    \endhead

    01247 & CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG & Gibson cloning\\
    01248 & GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG & Gibson cloning\\
    01249 & CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC & Gibson cloning\\
    01250 & GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG & Gibson cloning\\
    01251 & CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC & Gibson cloning\\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But I get a hell lot of errors:

```
\caption outside float. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
\caption outside float. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
\caption outside float. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
\caption outside float. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}
Overfull \hbox (7.21417pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (178.28296pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (76.84334pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (101.40483pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (76.84332pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (100.72044pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (10.95003pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Does anyone know, how to fix these?

Comment: `\caption` doesn't belong in `tabularx`.

Comment: You can use `\begin{table} \caption{...} \begin{tabularx}` instead.

Comment: You are mixing commands of at least three different packages. The macros `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` come from the `booktabs` package, while `\endhead` and `\endfirsthead` suggest you want to use a `longtable` from the eponymous package. Please clarify what your are trying to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a “long” `tabularx`, you need to load `ltablex`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,seqsplit,ltablex}

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  s{0.5}
  s{2}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}s{0.5}
  @{}
}
\caption[Oligonucleotides]{List of oligonucleotides ...}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence} & \textbf{Application}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence} & \textbf{Application}\\
\midrule
\endhead

01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01247 & \seqsplit{CACAGTATTGTCTTTCCCTGCTCCGCCAGGGACCTTGACTTTGAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01248 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGCCCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01249 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGGCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\
01250 & \seqsplit{GAAAGTGTCCCTGGAGACCCCTTCAAAGTCAAG} & Gibson cloning\\
01251 & \seqsplit{CTTGACTTTGAAGGGGTCTCCAGGGACACTTTCGTC} & Gibson cloning\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

You can use `\hsize=<fraction>\hsize`, but the sum of the fractional values should equal the number of `X` columns.

[image]